# "Seperation" is Evil

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spelling

I propose adding a feature to always replace "seperate" with "separate" in all question titles, questions, answers, edit summaries, and comments.

I'm asking just because I see it all over the place and, well, yes, it drives me a little nutty.

Perhaps `/\bsep(e)rat(ion|e|ly|ed)\b/ig.replace('$1', 'a')` or something close would do. I forget if javascript uses `$` for regex replacements.

**Update**

BAH HUMBUG!

Okay, I wasn't really serious. But it was fun to try. :)

Comment: Don't forget about all the other problems with the post as invariably there are.

Comment: @random Of course, but at least I'll be less tempted to edit unless I really have a material contribution.

Comment: I know this things are annoying, but keep in mind that not everyone is english native speaker; and, besides, if you start with "seperate", then you need to add other words. You might then end up with a full-blown spelling-checker, because just changing the word that gets more on your nerves won't be changing the root problem.

Comment: Donut no weather or not too +1 or -1. Their are sum good opportunities  to expound this.

Comment: This is a slippery slope.  I can probably think of a hundred other things that could also be automatically fixed.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. This could turn into a looooong list. It's probably not worth it. Not to mention misspellings that might actually be correct. (HTTP_REFERER anyone?) That said, the first word on my list for this would be "definately".

Comment: @Al: I was using satire to explain my downvote.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'm not quite sure what it is you're satirizing, but okay. I'll retract my comment.

Comment: @Al: grammar and spelling *insert Godwin's law reference here*.

Comment: maybe a really smart replacement algorithm for when 'then' should be 'than'

Comment: I don't think auto-spell checking algorithms are the way to go.  Most are able to decipher the original intent -- and if not, problems tend to be fixed quite quickly -- even, in sentences like:  "Me kno spel two gud.  Kno wright well I ether."

Comment: This would be a good opportunity for someone to earn a quick +1000 points suggesting edits to fix the spelling and grammar in all those posts.

Comment: @sarnold Isn't that only available to users under 1000 rep? I have almost 5000...

Answer (score 18):

I have just run

```js
$(".post-text p").each(function () {
    var wrong = $(this).text();
    var corrected = wrong.replace(/\b(sep)(?:e)(rat(?:ion|e|ly|ed))\b/ig, "$1a$2");
    $(this).text(corrected);
});
```

on this page, and now your suggestion doesn't make sense anymore:

> I propose adding a feature to always replace "separate" with "separate" in all question titles, questions, answers, edit summaries, and comments.

I hope my point is clear :)

Comment: I think you probably mean `/\b(sep)(?:e)(rat(?:ion|e|ely|ed))\b/ig` ... otherwise your regex will not change "seperately" to "separately".

Comment: So you're saying that someone, somewhere, in a secret project in the darkness of night miles from any living thing, while plotting to overthrow the world, could, imaginably, through an incredible series of extremely unlikely events, intentionally spell it "seperately." I see. Well, other than a meta discussion which references the word, I still think all invocations of the word could stand being adjusted. Since discussions about words would not be appropriate on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, I find myself doing this edit all the time.  A little automatic help would make sense, maybe don't apply it if it's in quotes.